Returning to karate at 78 after decades away
I'm 78, started karate at age 5. I quit practicing karate at age 23 after climbing to 1 dan, because I almost killed someone who attacked my daughter, due to major anger. I have not had anything to do with karate since then.
Now I have cancer, and am on cancer meds creating severe fatigue. I want to start up again to get back in shape, build muscle and stamina and health but do not remember much about being 1 dan. I hate to lose my belt after climbing up the belts, but right now I realize I am not a true 1 dan right now, probably not even a green belt right now.
What do I do. Start over?

"What do I do?" - talk to the instructor.

My dojo has a rule: 6 months or more without showing up = you start over. They keep this stuff in a database, along with names, join dates, and rank.

Be open about it and ask the coach. It is their call
It is quite common that people restart their martial arts decades after they stopped. Most times, they stop when their career starts (after high school/college/university) and get in contact again when their kids start the martial art but the reasons do not really matter.
As of what you do with your belt: You wear the belt that you achieved, full stop. That should be the default position. It does not matter when you did your testing or how much you remember. This can be communicated openly. Still, that is the grade you have. Given you join the same organisation, I hold that the belt should reflect your level of experience in that martial art and not your current prowess. That's what these belts usually mean. I have often experienced people starting with basics again and they usually catch up fast.
That being said, it is heavily dependent on the culture what one should do. I was explicitly asked to wear my (judo) black belt in jiu jitsu schools (not feeling very comfortable with it) just as I was asked to wear a white belt in a karate school of a different background while I had a higher grade doing basically the same but different.
Ultimately, though, a belt, or obi, is only that: something that serves to hold your clothes together. Westerners tend to read way too much into them, anyway.

I have a black belt in Taekwondo that I received at 18 years old. I'm now in my 50's. And I recently thought about getting back into it just because I want to improve my physical conditioning. I miss my youthful Taekwondo body and leg flexibility. I want some of that back. Haha.
But as for my rank, the only way I'm keeping my black belt is if the teacher allows it and the forms I learned are the same as the ones they're doing. But if either of those aren't true, then I would insist that I wear a white belt again. I prefer that, because then I have a chance to go through the foundational stuff again and build my way back up.
Throughout the years, I've received many belts in many martial arts. Each one, I had to start with a white belt. I always keep a white belt in my closet just in case. And honestly, it's a sheer joy putting on a white belt again. It means you're starting something. There's nothing but potential ahead. I can't think of anything more positive than that.
Black belts in karate are expected to teach lower ranks, too. If you're really fuzzy on all of what you learned a long time ago, then you're not ready to teach. You'll need to have a conversation with the head instructor of the school to make sure you're not put in that position. It might be a while before you're able to do things that the other black belts are doing.
Karate styles are all different. They have different forms they practice. They do different self-defense drills and one-steps. They have different ways of kicking and generating power. Everything you learned in your karate school earlier in life may end up being completely different in your new school.
So, until you come up to speed at the new school, you'll be in a bad position as a black belt. It's going to feel almost wrong. Lower ranking students will want you to answer questions, and you just won't know if your answers are "correct" at that school. You'll answer, but then you may learn you were wrong and taught the wrong thing by mistake. That's a bad feeling to have.
For the first year or so, you're going to be relentlessly corrected. Because, what you learned in the past is not only sloppy now but may also be wrong in the new school. The way you did things before maybe won't be the way things are done now in the new school. So you're going to go through a process of changing what you used to do habitually. Changing habits is hard to do. And that's going to be irritating for a while. It's going to force you to use your brain a lot more, which is actually useful for someone who's getting up in age and needs the mental workout as much as a physical one.
I always saw these differences as something to be excited about, personally. They show a different aspect on something you thought you knew. So my point is to keep an open mind, and when you're told to do something differently, it should make you very interested. This is something that will give you deeper insight into things.
My main advice is to talk with the head instructor for a while before joining up. See what they do. See if your stuff will need much correction. And tell the instructor you don't care about rank. You achieved black belt a long time ago, but that was a different you back then. You've forgotten a lot. Your body is much weaker. You're fine with wearing a white belt or any other belt so long as it's something the instructor says you should do. So leave it up to your instructor.
And then have a blast! Reconnect with your body and feel young again. Just go into it with an open mind, know what you want out of it, and keep to your own path.
Hope that helps!

No need to keep a white belt in reserve. One comes with every gi, or dobok, as the case may be.

@MichaelFoster That is true. They do. But I've used my white belt so many times it's not funny. Whenever I attend a workshop or seminar where a gi is expected, I never wear a black belt. Always a white belt. Whenever I practice in a fitness center or something, the white belt goes on. Haha. It represents an eternal beginner and learner. It's a mindset more than anything. I've seen many other black belts much more famous than I who just wear a white belt. Highly recommended.

Most styles will respect a rank that you have earned, whether or not you have been practicing since that time.
As an instructor, if you were to come in my school, I would walk you through a beginner form, and possibly intermediate/advanced form depending on how you did on the previous one(s). What I am looking for is muscle memory, balance, if I tell you "high section front punch" you know what I am saying, things of that nature.
Depending on how you do there, I will slot you into the appropriate level of classes. I would give you the option of wearing either your earned rank or assimilated rank. You would not be allowed to advance past 1st dan, however, until you had relearned all the relevant material. What I've found is that people that have earned a rank in the past relearn and go through the lower rank material at a fairly rapid pace.

Fully agreed. For "black belts" that show literally no or close to no kind of muscle memory or knowledge, I do ask them about where and how long they trained with whom. Seldomly, I even ask for credentials if none of this makes me think that there's actually truth to what they tell me. Happened only once but that's sad enough. No need to point out they never showed up again.
